# Can you have multiple schemas markups of the same type on one page?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org

I'm a dev for an AEM site and we have an FAQ Component that generates schema markup JSON with `"@type": "FAQPage"` for Google.  The issue is if the author adds two FAQ components to a single page there will be two schemas with the `"@type": "FAQPage"` in two different script blocks on the same page.  Is this allowed and best practice, or do I have to add something on the back end that will just generate one schema for all the FAQ components on a certain page?

Comment: Yes, that should work because Google aggregates the individual blocks. If in doubt, you can check your schema markup with the Schema Markup Validator or the Rich Results Test. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, `FAQPage` should only be defined once per page. This is because a single array object is expected.

**Required Properties**

| `MainEntity` |
| --- |
| `Question` - An *array* of Question elements which comprise the list of answered questions that this FAQPage is about. You must specify at least one valid Question item. A Question item includes both the question and answer. |

So if you want your pages to be eligible for rich results on Search and/or Actions on Google Assistant, you're going to have to work out a solution that generates one schema.

**Some other helpful guidelines:**

- The same FAQ content should not be used on multiple pages
- FAQ rich snippets on mobile typically choose the first 3
- Accordions are not a problem, and they won't be perceived as cloaking.
- You can't add schema for content that doesn't exist on the page you're adding it to.

Answer (score -2):

You Can Use Multiple Schema On Same Page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is too short to really be useful. Please consider editing it to explain your reasoning and put it in better context of the question. To me, it doesn't seem to actually attempt to answer the question that the original poster has about `FAQPage".